# Google Plus unable to read short links to Stack Exchange answers

Tags: bug, status-declined, answers, hyperlinks

Here's an interesting question on WebApps.SE:

**[Google Plus links to Stack Exchange questions and answers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/google-plus-links-to-stack-exchange-questions-and-answers)**

It's described as a Google Plus problem, but it may be a server config issue on the SE side. Nothing immediately visible from an inspection of the headers. More details [within](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/google-plus-links-to-stack-exchange-questions-and-answers/22200#22200).

Comment: I'm gonna hazard a guess that it's somehow related to redirecting to a URL with a fragment. But note that you can use the full answer URL and it'll work just fine.

Comment: Full answer URL works fine, full question URL works fine. SHORT question URL also works fine and no visible difference between the redirects for short question and short answer. So, a puzzle.

Comment: The visible difference is in the `#fragment`, like @Nine already commented. The redirect for the example question `Location: /questions/199569/where-to-maintain-central-source-repository` versus the troublesome example answer `Location: /questions/13267/git-and-mercurial/343603#343603`. I'd say it's a Google Plus problem, not understanding `301 Moved` with a fragment. Or, maybe there's [still no consensus](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Fragment/draft-bos-http-redirect-00.txt) about that?

Comment: I think my brain is malfunctioning a little. Cheers Nine and @Arjan. I thought I had tested the link with and without the fragment and got the same result, but I guess not. Testing bit.ly/ttA6vD [w. fragment] and bit.ly/sE65gN [w/o fragment] displays the observed behavior on G+. So it's a Google thing.

Comment: (I merged @Nine's findings and our comments into a suggested edit on [that answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/google-plus-links-to-stack-exchange-questions-and-answers/22200#22200). My reference to that draft RFC was moot, as that referred to fragments in *the original* URL.)

Comment: @Nine, I cannot test with Google Plus, but: the other tools fail on the full URL with a fragment too! Like: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fquestions%2F13267%2Fgit-and-mercurial%2F343603%23343603 yields "empty page" too.

Comment: Google be crazy. @Arjan's link above, once the fragment has been removed, works correctly: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fquestions%2F13267%2Fgit-and-mercurial%2F343603&view=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above and [the answer here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/22177/google-plus-links-to-stack-exchange-questions-and-answers/22200#22200), this is a Google bug and not a SE bug. Thanks to @Arjan and @Nine for the contributions.

Comment: Still then: as you also showed us that Google cannot handle this when automatically converting full sites for viewing on mobile devices, it *might* be nice if The Team can somehow create some workaround. But I'm afraid that would require client-side JavaScript (like: don't use the fragment in the `301 Moved` redirect, and then when seeing `/questions/13267/git-and-mercurial/343603`, add the fragment). Not too nice of a workaround, I assume?

Comment: I posted the issue on Google's forums: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=4dd9f0f36cde517e&hl=en It would be awesome if people can go there and star it so that it gets some attention from the Google moderators. @Arjan, the client-side hack could work - I don't think there's a use case where you would browse to an answer URL and _not_ want to see the answer in question, right?

Comment: I'm not sure when, but they fixed it. Follow this link to see the test cases that now work correctly in the Rich Snippets Testing tool:
http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=4dd9f0f36cde517e&hl=en